# How to add more then one array on same "for" in lua

Tags: lua

how can I use "for k, j in pairs() do" for 2 arrays in lua?

```
 local blipmarker1 = {
      { x = 10 , y = 5, z = 3 },
      { x = 5, y = 5, z= 3}
}
local blipmarker2 = {
      { x = 100, y= 150, z=30 }
}
function createtext(){
    local pos = GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId(), true)
    for k, j in pairs(blipmarker1,blimarker2) do
        draw3DText(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, j.x, j.y, j.z)
    end
 }
```

Comment: You can use a while loop and `next` to move through 2 arrays together. But i am unsure how the code in you post is expected to behave. Does the loop only run once? because blipmarker2 only has 1 value or does it run twice because blipmarker1 has 2 values and during the second loop blipmarker2 is nil

Comment: `for _, bm in ipairs{blipmarker1,blimarker2} do for k, j in pairs(bm) do .... end end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function **pairs()** accepts only one argument of type **table**. You need a loop for each table:

```
for k,j in pairs(blipmarker1) do
  ...
end
for k,j in pairs(blipmarker2) do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own stateful `multipairs` iterator.  Consult Chapter 9.3 “Coroutines as Iterators” of Programming in Lua for more details: https://www.lua.org/pil/9.3.html

```lua
local function multipairs(tables)
    return coroutine.wrap(function()
        for _, t in pairs(tables) do -- Maybe you want ipairs here
            for k, v in pairs(t) do
                coroutine.yield(k, v)
            end
        end
    end)
end

local blipmarker1 = {
    { x = 10 , y = 5, z = 3 },
    { x = 5, y = 5, z= 3}
}
local blipmarker2 = {
    { x = 100, y= 150, z=30 }
}

for _, j in multipairs{blipmarker1, blipmarker2} do
    print(j.x, j.y, j.z)
end
```